# Change meta key in Ubuntu Phone

Tags: ubuntu-touch, keyboard-layout, bq, wireless-keyboards, m10

I bought the BQ M10 Ubuntu edition tablet. I also got myself a Bluetooth keyboard with a swedish layout for it. 
On the swedish layout, the "alt gr" button is used to get some special characters, like 'at' and 'pipe' (not sure it's called that, but you get it).

When I try writing 'at' in the terminal by pressing 'alt gr'+2 i get:

> (alt: 2)

So it seems like 'alt gr' is set as the meta key, which is useless on most european keyboard layouts.

Does anybody know a way to change this?